# Passing One Stored Procedure’s Result as Another Stored Procedure’s Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Procedure 1:

```
EXEC Parse
@Part = '0123,4567'
@Qty = '1,1';
```

returns the following:

```
Part        Qty
0123         1
4567         1
```

This procedure simply takes a part and quantity input and parses the strings at each instance of ",".

Procedure 2:

```
EXEC PA
@Part = '0123'
@Qty = '1';
```

returns the following:

```
Top-Level Assembly     TotalQty      MaterialPart     Qty
      0123                1             12A            2
      0123                1             13A           21
      0123                1             14A            5
```

My overall goal is to have a user enter an assembly part or list of assembly parts (delimited by a comma) and their appropriate quantities. The first procedure creates a result list of all the assembly parts. The second procedure should run off of the result set from the first procedure to get all of the pieces that make up the assembly part.

How can I run my second procedure based off of the result of the first procedure? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What DBMS is this?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something else?

Comment: @Siyual it is SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temp table and iterate over the results in a `CURSOR`.  I'm making assumptions on your datatypes, so change as needed.

```
Create Table #Results 
(
    Part    Varchar (10),
    Qty     Int
)

Insert  #Results
Execute Parse @Part = '0123,4567', @Qty = '1,1';

Declare @cPart Varchar (10),
        @cQty Int

Declare cur Cursor Local Fast_Forward For 
    Select Part, Qty 
    From #Results
Open cur

While (1 = 1)
Begin
    Fetch Next From cur Into @cPart, @cQty
    If (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0) Break

    Execute PA @Part = @cPart, @Qty = @cQty
End

Close cur
Deallocate cur
```

Comment: Is there any way to create this cursor without creating a table?

The db I am using does not allow tables to be created; however, I can edit an empty table. I would need to create a key value though, something simple like assigning a key in numerical order would work.